# UITabelView scrollToRowAtIndexPath scroll to bottom sometimes will made my table disappear, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want my tableview scroll to the bottom when first time into the view, but sometimes won't scroll to the bottom, and sometimes will made my table disappear. (usually happened when first time or second time).

here's my scrolling code:

-(void)tableScrollToBottom{

```
[self.tableView reloadData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)]-1) inSection: ([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                  animated:YES];

});   
}
```

and I also have [self tableScrollToBottom] in viewDidAppear, cause if I only scroll the table in viewDidLoad the table always won't scroll to very bottom, and I don't know why, it's really confusing me.

And I tried to put [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded] in [self tableScrollToBottom], and remove the dispatch_async, it seems like the first time I opened the app and into the view still can't scroll to the very bottom, after the first time, it'll scroll to the bottom correctly, I don't know what's the difference between the first time open the app and into that view and after the first time.(my data get from server and it's from previous, and my tableview row height is dynamic).

here's my code in [self tableScrollToBottom] now:

```
-(void)tableScrollToBottom {

    [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];

    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)]-1) inSection: ([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

}
```

and here's where I called [self tableScrollToBottom] :

```
-(void)getDicData {

    for (int i = 0; i < _csDictArr.count; i ++) {

        [_chatPersonArray addObject:_csDictArr[i][@"Person"]];
        [_chatDataArray addObject:_csDictArr[i][@"Message"]];
        [_chatDateTimeArr addObject:_csDictArr[i][@"Time"]];                

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self tableScrollToBottom];

}
```

and I put [self getDicData] in ViewDidLoad, and I also call the tableScrollToBottom in viewDidAppear

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self tableScrollToBottom];

}
```

Comment: [Self.tableView reloadData] not enclosed in dispatch_async does that mean u r calling reload data in background thread ?? or you are calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath deliberately/unnecessarily on main thread ??

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know the difference :( but I tried to put [Self.tableView reloadData] in dispatch_async, now won't scroll to the very bottom everytimes, and sometimes will made my table disappear too.. I really don't know why..

Comment: Put a break point at [self.tableView reloadData]; when control stops go to console and type po [NSThread currentThread] if it prints main then u r calling [self.tableView reloadData]; already in main thread so dispatch_async is not needed else put [self.tableView reloadData]; also inside dispatch_async

Comment: it prints <NSThread: 0x174079d00>{number = 1, name = main}, so it means there's no need to put [self tableScrollToBottom] or [self.tableView reloadDate] in dispatch_async?

Comment: Nope. Dispatch_async and specifying main thread u are telling iOS that executes the segment inside this closure on main thread but if its already in main thread that does not add any value isn't it :) Moreover context switching like that are costly n should be used carefully :)

Comment: Thanks,  I removed the dispatch_async and I'll used it more carefully !

Comment: I have added an answer specifying why your tableView not scrolling for the first time. Please have a look :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use CATransaction to make sure tableView was reload completely before scroll it to bottom.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        CGFloat yOffset = 0;
        if (self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.bounds.size.height) {
            yOffset = self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height;
        }
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yOffset) animated:YES];
}];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: I tried to change the code like this, but it still can't scroll to the very bottom..

Comment: Firstly, make sure the previous data is correct and `tableView` is assigned `delegate` and `datasource` before method `tableScrollToBottom` is called.
Secondly, you might try with `viewDidLayoutSubViews`, instead of `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Notice: `viewDidLayoutSubViews` is called multiple times after view is load or rotation.